# dd-wrt DHCP forwarder is not working

Tags: routing, dhcp, rras

all. I have a network which a Windows server is running RRAS(192.168.6.1) and another Windows server is running DC,DNS,DHCP server (192.168.6.2). I added a dd-wrt flashed router. The client connects to VPN router need to communicate to the server too. So, I set the DHCP server to be DHCP forwarder by following the tutorial here : [tutorial](http://lab.stefanoperna.it/archives/tutorial-2/networking/linking-dd-wrt-routers-with-dhcp-forwarder-option/)

But, my clients connected to the VPN router are not given IP from my DHCP server (192.168.6.2). Below is my router configuration:

```
WAN Connection Type
--------------------
Connection Type: PPTP

Gateway (PPTP Server) : PPTP server

Username : username

Password : password

Use DHCP : No

WAN IP Address : 192.168.6.10

Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0

Gateway : 192.168.6.1

Static DNS 1 : 208.67.220.220

Static DNS 2 : 208.67.222.222

Static DNS 3 : 192.168.6.2

MPPE Encryption : Yes

Packet Reordering : Yes

Aditional PPTP Options : mppe required, no40, no56, stateless

Router IP
----------
Local IP Address : 192.168.6.10

Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0

Gateway : 192.168.6.1

Local DNS : 192.168.6.2


Network Address Server Settings (DHCP)
--------------------------------------
DHCP Type : DHCP Forwader

DHCP Server : 192.168.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't look at your tutorial, so I don't know much about your setup. But, DHCP is not normally used for a VPN. The VPN service will hand out the addresses to the clients on its own. At least this is the case for OpenVPN and PPTP.

Comment: Hi, Ryan. Thanks for the prompt reply. I just added the hyperlink on the first post. If I set the DHCP type to "DHCP server", the router will assign the Internal IP for the clients connected to the router. But, I wish the clients IP can be assigned by Windows Server DHCP instead of router so that the PCs connected to dd-wrt router or the server network can communicate.